# How do I get the key of object inside object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object and a for in loop that looks like this:

```
var golom = {
    MRTU03: {
        Temp: "10",
        Sp: "11"
    },
    MRTU09: {
        Temp: "8",
        Sp: "7"
    }
};
for (var f in golom) {
    $('body').append('hi ' + golom[f]);
}
```

As it is it's printing:

hi [object Object]hi [object Object]

to the `body`, but how can I get it to print

hi MRTU03hi MRTU09

??

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `golom[f]` with `f`. `f` is the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var f in golom) {
    $('body').append('hi ' + f);
    $('body').append('hi ' + golem[f].Temp); // Temp
    $('body').append('hi ' + golem[f].Sp); // Sp
}
```

Comment: Could be: for (var f in golom) {
    $('body').append('hi ' + f,'hi ' + f.Temp,'hi ' + f.Sp);
}

Comment: would it be `f.Temp` and `f.Sp`? or `golom[f].Temp` and `golom[f].Sp`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5GSJ/

Comment: @wirey It is actually, golom[f].Temp, but I have no idea why, f.Temp is undefined!

Comment: Can you fix this answer? f.Temp will always be undefined.

Comment: Answer fixed, strange!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var golom = {
    MRTU03: {
        Temp: "10",
        Sp: "11"
    },
    MRTU09: {
        Temp: "8",
        Sp: "7"
    }
};
for (var f in golom) {
    $('body').append('hi ' + f);
}
```